# belongs_to has_one associated record saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

If i have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end
```

.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Question:**
When i save an instance of Book, will it call save on its associated User as well?

In my code base im finding that when i call @somebook.save, 'User's after_save callbacks are being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an object to a belongs_to association does not automatically save the object. It does not save the associated object either.

Comment: Calling save on an object does not save the object?